# Use image texture from URL

Tags: materials

look up a few addons to Blender, the only one that I´ve found make a copy of the image to the project:

https://github.com/rymdnisse/http-image-jpeg

The fact is I need to use the relative URL from the image, to share the same file between teams without having to worry about to update the texture if somehow someone from other team changed, do you think it´s possible?

Comment: Is your file not on a shared local network? Why not use a third party syncing solution akin to dropbox?

Comment: That´s the fact we will like to make the file extremelly small on size, by doing that everybody that need to modified the file, will have to download the whole folder of the project and later be uploading again.